# Different label for a field in each form in a formset

Tags: django, django-forms

How can I have different label for a field in each form in a formset?  The solutions I've seen so far allow customization in a formset, but the same customization is applied equally for all fields in the forms in the formset.

What I currently to is store the label value as a hidden field inside the form.  Here's a form:

```
class RepairTypeForm(forms.Form):
  amount = forms.FloatField(required=False, min_value=0.01)
  repair_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
```

From the view I do this:

```
RepairTypeFormSet = formset_factory(RepairTypeForm)
repair_formset_values = [{'repair_name': 'Roof'}, {'repair_name': 'Walls'}]
repair_type_formset = RepairTypeFormSet(initial=repair_formset_values)
```

and the template:

```
{{ repair_type_formset.management_form }}
{% for form in repair_type_formset %}
  {{ form.repair_name }}
  <label for='{{ form.amount.auto_id }}'>{{ form.repair_name.value}}</label>{{form.amount}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do you want a different label, for displaying the form - or you want a hidden field when processing the form?

Comment: I want a different label for every form, and what I've mentioned is how I'm currently achieving it.  I would like not to use a hidden field to store the label name.

Comment: Forms don't have labels (only fields do). So what is the end result you want?

Comment: I need to have a different label for each field in a form in a formset.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your question?

Comment: The method I describe in this post is the solution I've been using.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it. I used get_form_kwargs method in the formset base class. Note that form_kwargs depends on the specific form instance.To give you some context... In my case I wanted to allow users to select an option for a bunch of different items. And wanted users to see the items.

```
from django.forms import formset_factory
from django import forms
from django.forms.formsets import BaseFormSet

class ActionForm(forms.form):
    choices = (
        ('Add', 'Add'),
        ('Remove', 'Remove')
    )
    action = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.Select, choices = choices)
    def __init__(self, item, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['action'].label = item


class ActionFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def get_form_kwargs(self,index):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(index)
        item = kwargs['items'][index]
        return {'item' : item}
#Views.py

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs)
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    items = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana']
    factory = formset_factory(ActionForm, max_num = len(items), formset=ActionFormSet)
    formset = factory(form_kwargs={'items':items})
    context['formset'] = formset
    return context
```